# How can I convert a date value in ISO 8601 format to a date object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601

I've been trying to convert a date value into a more readable format. To do that, I'm trying to parse the date using the JavaScript `Date.parse()` method. That however does not work on the input (eg: `"2007-09-21T14:15:34.058-07:00"`) that I have. The end goal is to output a date string like `"January 30th, 2008 @ 2:15PM"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: UTC is timezone 00:00. Do you mean ISO 8601 format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try http://www.datejs.com/. It is a JavaScript Date Library with an extended Date.parse method and a Date.parseExact method, which lets you specify a format string.
See [DateJS APIDocumentation](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation).

Comment: Worth pointing out that it doesn't seem perfect, and development seems to have halted. Example with the British file: `console.log(Date.parse('1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00'));` outputs null, and if the timezone part is removed it works, but in the American format (Wed Jul 16 1997 19:20:30 GMT+0100 (BST)), whereas "Wed 16th Jul, 1997…" would have been a bit more British.

Answer (score 20):

You should probably use the [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) that [f3lix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60617/) recommended, however I was bored and threw together a little object that does exactly what you asked for:

*September 25, 2012: Cleaned code, allow non-extended format, eg 20120925T164740+0200*

*December 1, 2011: fixed a bug in the month string. August was missing*

```
var ISODate = {
  convert :
    function (input){
      if (!(typeof input === "string")) throw "ISODate, convert: input must be a string";
      var d = input.match(/^(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2})[T ](\d{2}):?(\d{2}):?(\d{2})(\.\d+)?(Z|(?:([+-])(\d{2}):?(\d{2})))$/i);
      if (!d) throw "ISODate, convert: Illegal format";
      return new Date(
        Date.UTC(
          d[1], d[2]-1, d[3],
          d[4], d[5], d[6], d[7] || 0 % 1 * 1000 | 0
        ) + (
          d[8].toUpperCase() === "Z" ? 0 :
            (d[10]*3600 + d[11]*60) * (d[9] === "-" ? 1000 : -1000)
        )
      );
    },
  format :
    function(date, utc){
      if (typeof date === "string") date = this.convert(date);
      if (!(date instanceof Date)) throw "ISODate, format: t is not a date object";

      var t={'FullYear':0, 'Month':0, 'Date':0, 'Hours':0, 'Minutes':0, 'Seconds':0};
      for (var key in t) {
        if (t.hasOwnProperty(key)) t[key] = date["get" +(utc ? "UTC" :"") + key]()
      }

      return this.month[t.Month]
        + " "
        + this.ordinal(t.Date)
        + ", "
        + t.FullYear
        + " @ "
        + this.clock12(t.Hours,t.Minutes);
      },
  month:
    [
      "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ],
  ordinal:
    function(n) {
      return n+(
        [
          "th", "st", "nd", "rd"
        ][
          (( n % 100 / 10) | 0) === 1 ? 0 : n % 10 < 4 ? n % 10 : 0
        ]
      );
  },
  clock12:
    function(h24, m, s){
      h24%=24;
      var h12 = (h24 % 12) || 12;
      return h12 + ":" +
        (m < 10 ? "0" + m : m) +
        (isFinite(s) ? ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" + s : s ) : "") +
        (h24 < 12 ? "AM" : "PM");
      }
};
```

Example:

```
//Shows the date in the users timezone:
alert(ISODate.format("2007-09-21T14:15:34.058-07:00"));

//Show the date in UTC (Timezone Z, 00:00)
alert(ISODate.format("2007-09-21T14:15:34.058-07:00",true));
```

Explanation:

**convert** takes a string as an input and returns a date object if successful or throws an exception if not. The string must be in one of the following formats:

- YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ
- YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sXaa:bb

Where:

- YYYY is the year as an 4 digit integer
- MM is the month as an 2 digit integer
- DD is the date of month as an 2 digit integer
- T is the character T or space (\x20)
- hh is the hour in 24 hour format, as an 2 digit integer
- mm is the minute as an 2 digit integer
- ss.s is the second, either as an 2 digit integer or as a floating point with 2 digits followed by a period followed by one or more digits.
- Z is the character Z (indicating timezone Z, UTC+00:00)
- X is either a plus (+) or minus (-) sign of the timeoffset to UTC
- aa is the hour of timeoffset to UTC as a 2 digit integer
- bb is the minute of timeoffset to ITC as a 2 digit integer

**format** takes a string in the above format or a date-object and returns a string formated as:

- M D, Y @ h:mm

Where
  - M is the full English name of the month
  - D is the date of month with a numerical order suffix (1-2 digits)
  - Y is the year (1 or more digits)
  - h is the hour in 12 hour format (1-2 digits)
  - m is the minute (2 digits)

**month** is an array with the name of the months

**ordinal** is a function that takes a number as input and return the number with English ordinal suffix.

**clock12** is a function that takes hour, minute and second in 24h format and converts it to a string in the US 12h format. The *seconds* is optional.

Comment: This answer was very educational, but the first one i think is more poweful.

Comment: I agree that datejs is more powerful and I understand that you selected that answer.

Comment: datejs is more powerful but does have a footprint.  If the above conversion is all you need to do, use it.  But there is a minor bug - swap "this.month[t[1]-1]" instead of "this.month[t[1]]" in the format: method.

Comment: @Jeffrey Schrab: As I said at the top of my answer: "You should probably use the datejs...". There was a bug in the code but not where you thought it was. The zero-indexed-month is handled in the convert function. You actually introduced another bug with your fix. The real bug was in the array with the names of the months: It had no "August". Thanks for making me notice it!

Comment: This one is much better for me, looking for a lightweight solution for [talkatv](http://talka.tv).

Comment: @some You pass in 8 parameters to Date.UTC, but the method only takes 7. Is that a mistake or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Polshgiant Nope, you aren't missing anything. It was a mistake. Not harmful, but still wrong. Good catch! Fixed in the code above. Also refactored the code a bit: Allows non-extended format: 20120925T165102+0200 and extended: 2012-09-25T16:51:02+02:00.