# Convert UTC date format into javascript format

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

How can I convert a date from:
`Thu, 1 July 2011 22:30:00` to `'2011-07-01T13:51:50.417'` using javascript.

I get the UTC format when I do a new date.

IE causes me issues when I first create a date object as it shows: `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a new Date-Object and then get the different parts:

```
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear(); // Returns 2012
var month = today.getMonth()+1; // Returns the month (zero-based)
...
```

Then you can create a new string like you need it.

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate try search next time
[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498578/how-can-i-convert-a-date-value-in-utc-format-to-a-date-object-in-javascript?rq=1)

Try http://www.datejs.com/. It is a JavaScript Date Library with an extended Date.parse method and a Date.parseExact method, which lets you specify a format string. See DateJS APIDocumentation.

and then you can manipulate it as you want

Answer (score 0):

The d3.js library has some very solid routines for date conversions. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-parse.