# Converting JSON date string to a correct Date object

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help parsing ISO 8601 date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829569/help-parsing-iso-8601-date-in-javascript)

I think this should be very simple but turned out amazingly tedious.

From WEB API, I received `selected` object via ajax, and one of its properties is InspectionDate datetime string such as `2012-05-14T00:00:00`

In javascript, I use following code to have correct date object

```
selected.JsInspectionDate = new Date(selected.InspectionDate);
```

But JsInspectionDate shows

```
2012/05/14 00:00 in firefox, 
2012/05/13 20:00 in chrome and 
NAN in IE9
```

for `2012-05-14T00:00:00.`

Could someone tell me why this problem occurs? And how to fix this issue? I just want to show as in firefox for all browsers.

Comment: Looks like a timezone problem. 4 hours difference, do you live on the East Coast?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/498578/220060

Comment: @MikeRobinson yes I am in East Coast time zone

Comment: and also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4829569/220060

Comment: you are getting date in a string format?

Comment: Try `new Date(selected.InspectionDate + "Z")`. This fixes the timezone. But maybe this won't work on IE.

Comment: @nalply I am not sure I follow. I've already read those Q&A but why browsers produce different value? Do you mean that if I use datejs, all browsers will result in same date value?

Comment: @AshirvadSingh yes, ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API gives date in a string format.

Comment: datejs will help you, yes. The `+ "Z"` hack fixes the timezone (sets it to UTC), but if IE does not understand ISO dates, all is lost.

Comment: @nalply I will try it. Thanks why don't you make an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
new Date(selected.InspectionDate + "Z")
```

Rationale: Your dates are in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) form. Timezone designators like `"Z"`, a very short one for UTC, work.

**Note!** IE might not understand ISO 8601 dates. All bets are off. In this case, better use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Comment: Yeah datejs was way to go. Everything is in harmony now. To be honest, I didn't know datejs was requirement. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

First as one suggested, I tried following after referencing date.js.

```
selected.JsInspectionDate = Date.parse(selected.InspectionDate);
```

It seemed like working but later I found it was not enough since the JSON date string can have a format of `2012-05-14T00:00:00.0539` which date.js can't process either.

So my solution was

```
function dateParse(str) {
    var arr = str.split('.');
    return Date.parse(arr[0]);
}
...
selected.JsInspectionDate = dateParse(selected.InspectionDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tF6EA/)

```
var selectedDate='2012-05-14T00:00:00';
var formatttedDate=new Date(selectedDate.substr(0,selectedDate.indexOf('T')));

document.write(formatttedDate.getFullYear()+'/'+(formatttedDate.getMonth()<10?'0'+formatttedDate.getMonth():formatttedDate.getMonth())+'/'+formatttedDate.getDay());
```

Comment: This discards the time part. And why reinvent the wheel?