# Javascript timezone conversion displays NaN in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using the following javascript to convert UTC times into the users local timezone...

```
(function() {
  (function($) {
    return $.fn.localtime = function() {
      var fmtDate, fmtZero;
      fmtZero = function(str) {
        return ('0' + str).slice(-2);
      };
      fmtDate = function(d) {
        var hour, meridiem;
        hour = d.getHours();
        if (hour < 12) {
          meridiem = "AM";
        } else {
          meridiem = "PM";
        }
        if (hour === 0) { hour = 12; }
        if (hour > 12) { hour = hour - 12; }
        return hour + ":" + fmtZero(d.getMinutes()) + " " + meridiem + " " 
      };
      return this.each(function() {
        var tagText;
        tagText = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(fmtDate(new Date(tagText)));
        return $(this).attr("title", tagText);
      });
    };
  })(jQuery);
    }).call(this);
```

This all works fine in every browser apart from Internet Explorer, instead of converting the time it just displays 'NaN'

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Comment: What do the original dates in the HTML look like? Browsers differ in the variety of dates that they can parse with `new Date(...)`.

Comment: You can use "datejs" to handle date related stuffs.

Comment: The original dates are in this format '2012-02-07T13:30:00Z'

Comment: i made a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/6W6aL/

Comment: Internet Explorer does not support that (standardized) Date format in older versions and in Quirks mode, you will need to parse it manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a date value in ISO 8601 format to a date object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498578/how-can-i-convert-a-date-value-in-iso-8601-format-to-a-date-object-in-javascript)