# Current time in YouTube date API format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, youtube, iso8601

I am using the YouTube API and it returns uploaded & updated times in this format: 2013-05-13T13:12:42.000Z (ISO 8601). How can I get the relative time using Javascript (or jQuery)?

Some sources that I've tried to combine to get this to work, however they all appear to format the date differently.

[Javascript time to relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108819/javascript-timestamp-to-relative-time-eg-2-seconds-ago-one-week-ago-etc-best)

[Format ISO-8601 into a date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498578/how-can-i-convert-a-date-value-in-iso-8601-format-to-a-date-object-in-javascript?rq=1)

Comment: How do you want the date formatted?

Comment: In a way that can be read by the first link (Javascript time to relative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `timeDifference(new Date(), new Date().setTime(Date.parse("2013-05-13T13:12:42.000Z")))`

If you have a problem with the "(ISO 8601)" part, use this `timeDifference(new Date(), new Date().setTime(Date.parse("2013-05-13T13:12:42.000Z (ISO 8601)".replace(/ *\(.*\)/,""))))`

Answer (score 2):

### [**Click here to check the Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bRVLc/)

```
var MyDate = new Date(
                    Date.parse
                    (
                        "2013-05-13T13:12:42.000Z (ISO 8601)"
                        .replace(/ *\(.*\)/,"")
                    )
                );

var date_Str = MyDate.getMonth()      + 
                         1            + 
                       "/"            + 
               MyDate.getDate()       + 
                       "/"            +  
               MyDate.getFullYear();
```

Add more function

```
1. MyDate.getHours()
2. MyDate.getMinutes()
3. MyDate.getSeconds()
```

### **Result - "5/13/2013"**