# How do I convert to UTC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, highcharts

For highstock / highcharts I need the date format to be like this:

```
series: [{
    data: [[1331028000000, 5], [1331031600000, 6], [1331035200000, 4]]
}]
```

The first number in each array is the date-stamp, I think it is `UTC`. When I get the data that I need to put into the chart, I get it like this:

```
"2013-06-08T06:00:00.000-07:00"
```

My question is, what format is this? And how should I convert it to what I need for highstock / highcharts.

Comment: The format of `"2013-06-08T06:00:00.000-07:00"` is _ISO 8601_. `-07:00` is a timezone, `T` separates the date from the time. `1331028000000` is the time in _ms_.

Comment: UTC is a time zone, not a format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throw that string into a `Date()` function and you should get it back as a Javascript `Date` object.

```
var myDate = new Date('2013-06-08T06:00:00.000-07:00');
```

To get it back as a formal UNIX timestamp, you just need to convert it back to a number, and divide by `1000` (as there are a thousand `ms` in a second), but it looks like you're looking for the `ms` value, not a formal UNIX timestamp.

Easiest way would be to use the `+` prefix operator.

```
var myUnixTimestamp = +myDate;
// 1370696400000
```

Comment: @Watson ~ well, that's what your *ISO 8601* string says, so I'd be very worried if it didn't evaluate to that.

Comment: Is that line the same as var myUnixTimestamp = '' + myDate; ?

Comment: @Watson ~ no, there probably should be no space between `+` and `myDate`. Well, it should work with a space --- as the operator is probably defined --- I just find that it reads cleaner without.

Comment: To clarify concepts: classic Unix timestamps are in *seconds*. JavaScript uses *milliseconds*. Thus `1370696400000` is equivalent to the `1370696400` Unix timestamp.

Comment: @Watson `+x` in _JavaScript_ will do a cast to _Number_. For a _Date_, it will get the value in _ms_ since the unix epoch.

Comment: What is going on there then? Its not like +=

Comment: @Watson ~ in Javascript, the `+` operator has three purposes: `arithmetic addition` (e.g. `var foo = 1 + 2;`), `string concatenation` (e.g. `var foo = 'hello' + 'world';`) and `number casting` (e.g. `var foo = '123'; var bar = +foo;`). The use of `+=` is just a combination of operation and assignment.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `+'123' === 123`, `+'-123' === -123`, etc, but `+'abc'` is `NaN`, not `0`.

Comment: @PaulS. ~ as well as the difference in behavior between `+'123a'` and `parseInt('123a')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var date = new Date("2013-06-08T06:00:00.000-07:00");
    console.log(date.getTime());
  //or console.log(date.valueOf());
```

Comment: Er... Aren't you missing something? This code basically converts `1331028000000` to `1331028000000` ;-P

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: just a sample code. The point is using date.getTime() or date.valueOf() to convert to milli-seconds since 01/01/1970 (UTC time)

Comment: @Watson: updated, you have already accepted the other answer. Maybe you can see it as reference for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its millisecond, try using below code.

```
var date = new Date(1331028000000);
console.log(date.toString())
```

Comment: `Tue Mar 06 2012 11:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora de verano romance)`... as [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString).

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498578/how-can-i-convert-a-date-value-in-iso-8601-format-to-a-date-object-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498578/how-can-i-convert-a-date-value-in-iso-8601-format-to-a-date-object-in-javascript) may also help you.